# drop down code for store locator on magento

Tags: javascript, html, css, magento

Please can anyone help with the code for a drop down for store locator in magento,this is a look alike of what i want to achieve:

http://www.watchrepublic.co.za/store-locator.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Magento, but after a bit of googling, I came across a [drop down menu extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/responsive-custom-menu.html).

Comment: Thank you, this will not work for me,I want a drop down as a page content to show lists of stores.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'd make a custom module for this. Take a look at this to serve frontend files like the menu you'd like to make.

http://alanstorm.com/magento-2-frontend-files-serving/

Create all the routes and then call the Menu within your default.xml

```
 <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="responsive.new.menu" template="Yourtheme_Menu::responsiveMenu.phtml />  
 </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately am new to coding and I really do not seem to understand what you have said,will appreciate if you can explain further

Comment: Whoa. If you want to do it by yourself, if you use another E-commerce that is much simpler than magento can help you out. This is a very complicated system.   Another easier option is to install a theme that already has the menu that you're looking for.  try in www.themeforest.net and install it. Its a much simpler way to go thru this